# The ball take away a submanifold of codimension 1 is a domain of holomorphy

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathbb{B}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be the unit ball and $V \subset \mathbb{B}^n$ be a closed complex submanifold of codimension one.  How do we show that $\mathbb{B}^n \setminus V$ is a domain of holomorphy?

Showing that $\mathbb{B}^n \setminus V$ is a domain of holomorphy is equivalent to showing that there is a holomorphic function on the domain that is singular at every boundary point.

Comment: Say $V$ is the zero-set of a holomorphic function $f$. Then what?

Comment: The complement need not be open. Do you want to add an extra assumption?

Comment: @TedShifrin I could take a holomorphic function $g$ on the ball which is singular at every boundary point.  Then $(1/f) + g$ would be singular at every boundary point of $B^n \setminus V$ and I would be done.

Comment: @TedShifrin $V$ locally is the zero-set of holomorphic functions.  I would like to use a partition of unity to patch together the different holomorphic functions whose zero sets are locally equal to portions of $V$.  But then I wouldn't get a holomorphic function.  Is there a way to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks.  I added the relatively closed assumption

Comment: I would suggest thinking about Čech cocycles. Do you know that $H^1(B^n,\mathscr O^*)=0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin  No, I don't know what those are.

Comment: Relatively closed is not good enough. You have to remove a closed submanifold. Do you know the definition of a *domain* in complex analysis?

Comment: You should also read about [Cartan's Theorems A and B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorems_A_and_B). These (and their applications!) are discussed in detail all standard sources on SCVs and should be a standard part of your toolkit.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for pointing me towards those theorems

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't understand why relatively closed would not be good enough.  To answer your question, a domain is an open and connected set.  The ball minus a relatively closed set would remain open.  Since a submanifold of (complex) codimension 1 is (real) codimension 2, it would not disconnect the ball.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misread what you wrote. It is all good now.